# Rails Ajax JS vs JSON confusion

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

Using Rails 4, I want to use Ajax form post using :remote => true and I want to be able to get back the response in json format so I can make use of any error messages in case of failure.

The form post is hitting my controller action fine. Controller action:

```
def create
    @comment_hash = comment_params
    @obj = @comment_hash[:commentable_type].constantize.find(@comment_hash[:commentable_id])
    @comment = Comment.build_from(@obj, current_user.id, @comment_hash[:body])
    respond_to do |format|
        if @comment.save
            if @comment_hash[:reply_to].to_i > 0
                @parentcomment = Comment.find(@comment_hash[:reply_to].to_i)
                @comment.move_to_child_of(@parentcomment)
            end

            format.js { render :template => "comments/create.js.erb", :status => :created }
        else
            format.js { render :template => "comments/create.js.erb", :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

The controller action will render the create.js.erb regardless of success or error as expected. But if I include format.json it will never respond using json. I think this is because Ajax remote: true requests will always respond using js.

1. How do I get the ajax request to respond with json?
2. With this observation that rails ajax requests respond with js format, I am further confused by the example provided here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html where the successful save response provides the js format but the error response does not provide any js format.

I would think this would error for an ajaxError response because the js format is not available?:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.js   {}
      format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The controller action will render the create.js.erb regardless of success or error as expected. But if I include format.json it will never respond using json. I think this is because Ajax remote: true requests will always respond using js

First off, your assumption is incorrect.  Rails `remote: true` hooks into what's known as the UJS driver, which makes a lot of the work involved in making an XHR request simpler.  However, you could achieve the same behaviour by having a `form_for` or `form_tag` and handling the form submission purely in JS via jQuery's excellent `$.ajax()`.

I'd suggest you first delete the `create.js.erb` - this will always be processed to return a script response, and you want to render JSON instead.

You can also be a bit more explicit here,

```
format.json { render json: { @user, status: :created, location: @user } }
```

Under the covers, Rails is calling `#to_json` on your Ruby objects such as AR models, to simple Hashes.

Once you've removed the `create.js.erb`, go the view where you are rendering your form.  Look for the `form` element in the DOM, you can casually look for it via the inspector console via `$('form')`.  It's better to identify it via a class or directly, its id.  Let's assume your form's selector is `$('#comments-form')`.

You'll want to add another JS file to your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` Sprockets manifest, and inside that file

```
$(function(){
    var $commentForm = $('#comments-form');

    $commentForm.on('ajax:error', function(e, xhr, status, error) {
        console.log('Error: %O', $(this).append(xhr.responseText));
    });

    $commentForm.on('ajax:success', function(e, data, status, xhr) {
        console.log('Data: %O', data);
    });

});
```

The JS snippet above is a start, and will fire when those [jquery-ujs events](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) are triggered, placing debugging output into the console.  On an XHR error, you'll get error info, on success the JSON data will be shown instead.

**Addendum**:

The `format.js` in the respond_to block is purely for processing the `create.js.erb`, which in the example provided does this `$("<%= escape_javascript(render @user) %>").appendTo("#users");` - it uses the user instance to figure out the DOM selector, and appends that to a DIV with id 'users' into the DOM.

Personally, I find it's simpler to stick to JSON for consistencies sake and achieve the same behaviour via the success handler, although YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for this info this confirmed that my assumptions with rendering json were incorrect I assumed that I would need to render a particular file to handle the json response similar to how html or js format would be handled

Comment: Im not sure I like the idea of adding additional js files to application.js - do you do this to DRY up the Ajax handling architecture across multiple models? I would have thought say app/js/user.js.erb could handle the user related Ajax?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with adding JS files to application.js - Yes, they are globally accessible app-wide.  You can add a page unique class to the `body` element, and check if that class exists, thereby running page-specific code.  Another option is to add the file to your `config/initializers/assets.rb` (Rails 4) and render that JS file specifically for the view via `<% content_for :footer_javascripts do %>...<% end %>` and make sure you're yielding to `:footer_javascripts` in your application base-layout.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just to be clear, answering my question part 2. After for analysis my understanding is that if @user.save fails and this is an Ajax request, the default response format ujs looks for is js, as js is not specified it would look for the default route - in this case would be create.js.* (eg erb) if that file is not found would then respond with json. This is what I have observed.

Comment: I was thinking to try to take advantage of rails convention over configuration with hooking into the default user.js.erb also helps with compartmentalization however I agree that moving generic shack stuff into the sprockets manifest makes sense. Thanks again

Comment: @joshweir: i was wondering the exact same thing at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41621554/rails-remote-true-confusion-no-format-js and my conclusion is the same: there is some kind of "default fallback route" for JS format requests

Comment: I think part of the confusion is because Rails scaffolds controllers with format.json and not format.js. And Rails 5.1 form_with defaults to using remote ajax forms which rely on format.js which is not in the scaffold. So one has to add format.js to their controllers. And that breaks the idea of convention over configuration.