# Rails remote => true confusion (no format.js?)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, asynchronous

I am trying to learn how to use rails with remote => true on forms.

The following example on the ruby on rails official website confuses me. It works perfectly even if there is no "`format.js`" code when the `@user.save` call fails.

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
# ......
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.js
      format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I was expecting an error response because the js format is not available.  What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer i was looking for on IRC.  The answer is from https://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms-data-type-with-jquery/:

> Newer versions of the UJS driver simply leave jQuery's default
>   dataType of '/'. This tells the server, "Give me whatever you've got."
>   However, this would make the controller respond with the first format
>   that happens to be listed in the Responder (see next section). So if
>   format.html is listed before format.js, the app will respond with the
>   HTML response (which means it will try redirecting for POST or DELETE
>   method AJAX requests). This isn't ideal either.
>
> So in the newest versions, we figured out how to set the default, such
>   that it tells the server, "I'd prefer JS, but I'll take whatever
>   you've got." Now, if format.js is defined at all in the available
>   Responder formats, JS will be returned. If not, the controller will
>   then respond with the first format listed. (See the discussion thread
>   here.)

discussion thread: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/74